# SQL Server Distinct on Earliest Date in a Timestamp Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table called 'Audit' in SQL Server 2005 like this:

```
Name    | Last Logged On Date
--------| -----------------------
Joe     | 2012-02-01 00:00:00.000
Joe     | 2012-02-02 00:00:00.000
Bloggs  | 2012-03-01 00:00:00.000
Bloggs  | 2012-03-02 00:00:00.000
```

I want to only get the distinct on the first time the person logged on.

So in other words, I want to return:

```
Name    | First Logged On Date
--------| -----------------------
Joe     | 2012-02-01 00:00:00.000
Bloggs  | 2012-03-01 00:00:00.000
```

How would I achieve this?

Help!!!

Comment: the spaces in your column names are slowly killing me... aaahhhhhh

Comment: hehe sorry - I'll correct it in my next post to SO :)

Comment: I just hope your production tables don't have spaces in the column names!

Comment: Nope they dont...I added the spaces to be more easily readable in SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question right, it should work for you

```
SELECT Name, MIN([Last Logged On Date]) AS [First Logged On Date]
FROM Audit
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Yes that worked beautifully...it looks so simple when you know how :D Thank you very much.